# DB diff between before and after, export db to txt

Tags: sql-server, diff, export

I have to see a difference between 2 states of the same DB (MS SQL 2008). Profiler is not an option as it is run-time tool and needs operator actions.

I have not found tools for this purpose, so the question is - is there a way to export DB data into human-readable text format to compare them with something like windiff?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

I know redgate offers a product to do a [Schema](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Compare/index.htm) and a [Data](http://www.red-gate.com/products/SQL_Data_Compare/index.htm) differential.  I've personally never used it, but I've seen various demos and it sounds like it might do what you need.  There is also a utility that came with SQL Server 2005 called [TableDiff](http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/03/03/60125.aspx), that lets you compare two tables that you could probably script to compare more if needed.